# How to print image to a pdf in python without saving image to disk first

Tags: python, image, pdf, python-imaging-library

I am making a scraper for my personal use that takes screenshots and saves them to a pdf. I am using pyscreenshot to take the screenshot and this returns a PIL image (PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile to be precise). I am using FPDF to make the pdf and can use the image method to add an image to the pdf.

The trouble is, this takes in either a file path or a URL. It is my understanding that saving many things to the disk will cause wear, so ideally I would like to save the image to the pdf straight from the PIL object instead of saving the image first. I'll be taking around 1500 screenshots, is this an unnecessary worry?

I am using Ubuntu if that changes anything. Here are the docs for the image method: [https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/image/index.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Here are the relevant parts of my code.

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from fpdf import FPDF

def get_page_image():
    page_image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox = half_page_bbox)
    page_image.save("Test image 1.png")
    return image

half_page_bbox = (249, 1, 1672, 1028)

pdf = FPDF("P", "mm", "A4")
pdf.add_page()
page_image = get_page_image()
pdf.image("Test image 1.png", 10, 10, 100)
pdf.output("My pdf.pdf")
```

I have tried using io to save it in memory, but this isn't working. Here is my code followed by the error.

```
import io
tmpFile = io.BytesIO()
image.save(tmpFile, format='png')
tmpFile.seek(0)
pdf.image(tmpFile, 10, 10, 100)
```

```
in <module>
    pdf.image(tmpFile, 10, 10, 100)
  File "/home/henry/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 150, in wrapper
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/henry/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 963, in image
    pos=name.rfind('.')
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Comment: Any particular reason to use software that hasn't been updated for years for a new project?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ignorance would be the primary reason, I'll have a look at other modules to use. Was there anything you would suggest in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following, note that I'm using `fpdf2` instead of `fpdf`

`pip install fpdf2`

```py
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from fpdf import FPDF

img = ImageGrab.grab()

pdf = FPDF("P", "mm", "A4")

pdf.add_page()

pdf.image(img, 10, 10, 100)

pdf.output('My pdf.pdf')
```